# Couchbase .NET client server list round robin lookup

Tags: couchbase

I have a couchbase cluster of 4 nodes running in production. I am using a .NET client to connect to this cluster. My problem is the Servers List that we have to provide. The docs say that while initializing the Cluster object it goes through these list of Servers and whoever returns first with cluster meta data is used to initialize it.

My site has a lot of traffic and I observer that since Server1 is the first server in this list and my App tier is close to 10 servers the CPU load on this Server goes very high to the point that it goes down. To solve this I have add a reverse proxy in between which as per the docs is not the right way. Could you please help me with how I can randomize the server selection behavior or what values should I use for connection persistence etc. I have tried a lot of things but nothing works.

Comment: It might help if you list what version of the .NET SDK you are using and version of Couchbase as well.

Comment: CouchBase Server version is 3.0

Comment: What is the SDK version? The new 2.0 .NET SDK went GA just a few weeks ago. I want to make sure you are not using a beta of 2.0 and if a 1.x version which one. On a completely different note, I highly recommend you upgrade to at least 3.0.1 if you can.

Comment: What SDK version are you using?